# Python - Converting Datetime objects in series while keeping non-date time objects the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have the following series:

```py
myseries = pd.Series([' Period : From 1 February 2020 to 31 January 2021',
                         ' Period : 1 January 2020 to 31 December 2020',
                         ' Period 67 months',
                         ' Period: 8 Months'])
```

I want to convert the datetime objects where there are two dates (only the first 2) into datetime format, while keeping the others in their original format.

i.e - `[('02-01-2020', '01-31-2021'), ('01-01-2020', '12-31-2020'), 'Period: 67 Months', 'Period: 8 Months']`

I tried the following, but I'm getting a datetime object for the ones that don't have a proper date.

```py
for i,v in myseries.iteritems():
    matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(v))
    if len(matches) > 0:
        print(matches)
```

I've tried using the `staticmethod` argument in datefinder's `find_dates()`, which gives me the following. I can work with this however, I'm unable to extract the objects I require.

```py
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0), '1 February 2020'), (datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 31, 0, 0), '31 January 2021')]
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0), '1 January 2020'), (datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0), '31 December 2020')]
[(datetime.datetime(2067, 4, 4, 0, 0), '67 mon')]
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 8, 0, 0), '8 Mon')]
```

My desired output is 2 lists:

```py
date_1 = ['1 February 2020', '1 January 2020', '67 mon', '8 Mon']
date_2 = ['31 January 2021', '31 December 2020', '67 mon', '8 Mon']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
myseries.apply(lambda x: [x[1] for x in datefinder.find_dates(x, source=True)][:2] if not pd.isna(x) else [])
```

Basically, use the source parameter to get the original date, then if the list of dates is bigger than 2, get the first 2.

If you want date_1 and date_2:

```
date_1 = []
date_2 = []

dates = myseries.apply(lambda x: [x[1] for x in datefinder.find_dates(x, source=True)][:2])
for date in dates:
    if len(date)==0:
        date_1.append(np.nan)
        date_2.append(np.nan)
    if len(date)>0:
        date_1.append(date[0])

    if len(date)>1:
        date_2.append(date[1])

    elif len(date)>0:
        date_2.append(date[0])
```

Comment: In case there is no date present `date_2.append(date[0])` gives me 'list index out of range'. How would I get around that?

Comment: Just edited, it was because the else didn't account for that fact, sorry!

Comment: Thanks! I just have one last question. If there are some NaN values in my series which don't get appended to the list, is there a way to include those? As I would like to append my results back into the series

Comment: See now, I have put to if there aren't any dates it will put Nan in date_1 and date_2